# How to write many rows to excel file portion by portion to decrease consumption of RAM

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to write ~500.000 rows to excel file with openpyxl. These rows are generated on flight (all of them can't be stored in RAM simultaneously because of big size). So I want to generate first 50.000 rows (which I can store in memory) and dump them to file on disk. Then I want to delete these rows from RAM, generate new 50.000 rows, and append them to file (with first 50.000 rows). ... Until I write all 500.000 rows to file.

My code is the following:

```
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.Workbook()
book.remove(book.active)
sheet = book.create_sheet("Results")

for i in range(500000):

    row = []
    # ... Fill row with data
    sheet.append(row)

    if i % 50000 == 0:
        book.save('my_file.xlsx')
        sheet = None # Large amount of data are deleted from RAM
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook('my_file.xlsx')
        sheet = book.active
```

But when I watch RAM consumption I don't see any effect. It grows despyte of my tricks. What is wrong in my approach? And what I should do to write big amount of data to file portion by portion.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure, try putting the row content filling logic into a function, what you call many times(500 000) after it.

```
import openpyxl

def row_content(sheet):
    row = []
    # ... Fill row with data
    sheet.append(row)

book = openpyxl.Workbook()
book.remove(book.active)
sheet = book.create_sheet("Results")

for i in range(500000):

    row_content(sheet)

book.save('my_file.xlsx')
```

What I think is that the garbage collector will handle some of your extra data as you used a function.

Comment: Thanks for answer, SzabBence! But I think that book.sheet (not row or data which I use calculating row) consumes main amount of RAM. And I think when I load book openpyxl fills sheet with all data contained in book, so saving and loading file doesn't affect memory consumption.